# All possible system keyspaces in Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to find a list of all the possible 'System' keyspaces that MAY exist in a DSC Cassandra database (System keyspaces are those which are not created by a user).

My experience thus far is I have found

```
[cqlsh 3.1.8 | Cassandra 1.2.15 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]
system system_traces OpsCenter
```

Are these the only available System Keyspaces or are there others? Does it depend on the version(1.2/2.0) and distribution(Apache/Datastax)?
I tried to search the documentation but no luck. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `system`, `system_auth` and `system_traces` are strictly "System", especially the 1st one. 
`OpsCenter` is created for/by DataStax OpsCenter

Comment: Would it be safe to assume all cassandra keyspaces  begin with 'system'? Also, what would be the repercussions if 'OpsCenter' was deleted (would it be created again/ would it render OpsCenter unusable)?

Comment: Based on my preliminary understanding, I guess deleting OpsCenter would require us to provision all the clusters again, and though the keyspace would be generated, it would not be populated until provisioning is done.